# How to add a parameterized super interface in JavaPoet?

Tags: java, annotation-processing, javapoet

I am writing an annotation processor that generates JSON serialization code. Here's my annotation that I use to identify the `POJO`s that need a serializer

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface JsonSerialize {

}
```

And here's the base interface of my serializer

```java
public interface JsonSerializer<T> {

    String serialize(T t);

}
```

Here's the annotation processor code that looks for that annotation and generates the serializer code

```
@Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(JsonSerialize.class)) {
            if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS) {

                MethodSpec serializeMethod = MethodSpec
                        .methodBuilder("serialize")
                        .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                        .addParameter(ParameterSpec.builder(TypeName.get(element.asType()), "obj", Modifier.FINAL).build())
                        .returns(String.class)
                        .addStatement("return \"dummy string\"")
                        .build();

                TypeSpec serializer = TypeSpec
                        .classBuilder(element.getSimpleName().toString() + "JsonSerializer")
                        .addSuperinterface(JsonSerializer.class) // THIS LINE IS WRONG
                        .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                        .addMethod(serializeMethod)
                        .build();

                try {
                    JavaFile.builder(processingEnv.getElementUtils().getPackageOf(element).toString(), serializer)
                            .build()
                            .writeTo(processingEnv.getFiler());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But I get a compile error, because my generated class is not specifying the generic parameter in it's inheritance. How can I specify that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing a `java.lang.Class` to the `addSuperinterface` method, you'll need to pass something with the specific type details you have in mind. This method has two overloads - one which takes `java.lang.reflect.Type` (and `Class` is a subtype of this), and another which one which takes `com.squareup.javapoet.TypeName`). Technically either works, though since you are already using JavaPoet, I'd encourage trying to create the TypeName instance.

`TypeName` has a number of subclasses, `ClassName`, `ParameterizedTypeName` are probably the main ones to focus on here. In an annotation processor, they have some big advantages over using a `Class` instance - mostly that you don't need to actually be able to load or reference the class you are talking about - kind of like how you are using `element.getSimpleName().toString()` elsewhere in your code.

These classes have static methods to create them, which can be based on a variety of things. The one we're interested in here is this:

```
  /** Returns a parameterized type, applying {@code typeArguments} to {@code rawType}. */
  public static ParameterizedTypeName get(ClassName rawType, TypeName... typeArguments)
```

In you code, you would use it roughly like this:

```
    ...
    .addSuperinterface(ParameterizedTypeName.get(
            ClassName.get(JsonSerializer.class),//rawType
            ClassName.get(whateverTShouldBe)    //the value for T
    ))
    ...
```

Chance are excellent that `T` could eventually be generic here too, like `List<String>`, so you should take care to properly build the type which is passed in there - it might itself be a `ParameterizedTypeName`. Keep an eye on the various methods in `TypeName` for this too - the `TypeName.get(TypeMirror)` overload for example will take an already-parameterized declared type mirror and give you the expected `ParameterizedTypeName` back again.

With that said, according to your other code, `T` today cannot be generic - you look for the `@JsonSerialize` annotation on an `Element`, which means it would be the equivelent of `List<T>` rather than the usage of it, `List<String>`. Then, in this line, you make the Element into a TypeMirror to build the type name as I've described above:

```
    .addParameter(ParameterSpec.builder(TypeName.get(element.asType()), "obj", Modifier.FINAL).build())
```

This means the final code would probably be

```
    ...
    .addSuperinterface(ParameterizedTypeName.get(
            ClassName.get(JsonSerializer.class),//rawType
            TypeName.get(element.asType())    //the value for T
    ))
    ...
```